# How do I access a mathematical operation within a dictionary based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def calculator():
    print("When prompted to enter a symbol, enter:\n'+' to add,\n'-' to subtract,\n'*' to multiply,\n'/' to divide,\n'^' to calculate powers,")
    print("',\n'=' to get the answer.")
    again = None
    while again != "x":
        answer = float(input("\nEnter number: "))
        while 1 == 1:
            symbol = input("Enter symbol: ")
            if symbol == "=":
                print("\nThe answer is ", answer, ".", sep = "")
                again = input("\nEnter 'a' to use the calculator again and 'x' to exit: ")
                break
            number = float(input("Enter number: "))
            dictionary = {"+": operator.iadd(answer, number), "-": operator.isub(answer, number), "*": operator.imul(answer, number), "/": operator.itruediv(answer, number), "^": operator.ipow(answer, number)}
            dictionary[symbol]
```

The program seems to work, but whenever I ask for the answer, it just shows me the first number I inputted; it doesn't seem to be using the dictionary at all.

Comment: What did you expect `dictionary[symbol]` to do, given that you neither assign nor do anything with the value? And why are you rebuilding the dictionary every time through the loop, rather than storing the operator functions in it? And *why is it named `dictionary`?!*

Comment: I expected it to access the value of the key it matches. Sorry, I was facing some errors when I originally kept it outside the loop, I was going to fix it once. "Dictionary" is just more straightforward (for e.g., in "for" loops, I name the variable "loop").

Comment: It does access that value, but *doesn't do anything with it*. Maybe `print` it, at least.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks! It worked. But I still have to keep the dictionary in the loop as it processes values as soon as I make the dictionary (and I can't assign 0, 1, or "None" to them before storing the values in the dictionary as that messes up the answer or gives me an error. Any way of having the dictionary not process before I tell it to?

Comment: Yes, you can just store the functions themselves in the dictionary, then do `result = dictionary[symbol](answer, number)`. That way you don't have to calculate four values you don't even need.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks a lot, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the the result of operator method back to `answer`:

```
dictionary = {
    "+": operator.iadd(answer, number), 
    "-": operator.isub(answer, number), 
    "*": operator.imul(answer, number), 
    "/": operator.itruediv(answer, number), 
    "^": operator.ipow(answer, number)
}

answer = dictionary[symbol]
```

Or, a better way would be to just store the method:

```
dictionary = {
    "+": operator.iadd, 
    "-": operator.isub, 
    "*": operator.imul, 
    "/": operator.itruediv, 
    "^": operator.ipow
}

answer = dictionary[symbol](answer, number)
```

Comment: Would it be better programming practice to keep the dictionary on multiple lines or one if it's this size (as in, it fits on the screen without scrolling)

Comment: @NeelKamath note that the Python style guide sets an 80-character limit on lines.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do indents count as characters? Cuz I understand why the limit is 80 cuz when you put 2 codes side-by-side you can't read more than 80, but with indentation it's kinda hard to put everything on a new line without having a million "+" signs

Comment: Yes, indents count. There are existing posts here and elsewhere on holding to this limit (whether, how, etc.). Also it's *"[be]cause"* and *"kind of"*.